# Allow unregistered paypal users to make payments

Tags: paypal

Hi i am integrating paypal web payments standard into my shopping cart using the setup where you just send a form to paypal with all the values in  hidden fields. I want to enable the option that allows people to make payments even if they are not a registered paypal user. I am sure i read somewhere in the paypal documentation but now i can't find it.

Thanks a lot
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is do-able. You can find all the info on paypal site. Here's one:
[Website Payments Standard: Integration Overview](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-standard-integration-outside)

However there's one catch. If the buyer uses an email or a credit card that was registered in Paypal before, he/she will be forced to login. Else a new email address or card number has to be used.

Comment: Yeah i have alread read the documentation, you have just told me what i already know

Comment: Well, guess you have to dig deeper :)